# why Substitute(variable_x) get a numeric value instead of 'name' object

Tags: r

These are my codes:

```
divider <- function(numerator, denominator){
    if(denominator == 0)
    {
        message(class(substitute(denominator)))
    }
    numerator / denominator
}
divider(3, 0)
```

Its result is 'numeric'(version R 3.4.3), i couldn't understand this. It should be 'name' object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will only be `name` if you pass it a named object; try the following:

```
divider <- function(numerator, denominator){
    if(denominator == 0)
    {
        message(class(substitute(denominator)))
    }
    numerator / denominator
}
x = 3
y = 0
divider(x, y)

# name
# [1] Inf

divider(3, 0)

# numeric
# [1] Inf
```

As pointed out by [Moody_Mudskipper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2270475/moody-mudskipper) in the comments to the answer, this is explained in the help file for `substitute()` (see `help("substitute")`):

> The mode of the result is generally "call" but may in principle be any
>   type. In particular, single-variable expressions have mode "name" and
>   constants have the appropriate base mode.'

Comment: Oh my god! I didn't notice the difference between named object and just a '0'. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Tal No problem, glad it helped!

Comment: @Tal .And right from `?substitute` : 'The mode of the result is generally "call" but may in principle be any type. In particular, single-variable expressions have mode "name" and constants have the appropriate base mode.' . The help page of many functions (especially base functions)  has a 'Value' section that you should check right away when you have this kind of issues.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Good quote from the help file. I'll add that in as explanation at the end (with appropriate credit of course)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Although I had read the help page, i didn't catch it.. so sorry for that. And thanks for you device.:)